# TestNG console output is different every time for same tests on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, intellij-14

So basically I'm running a simple test on Intellij CE 14.1.4 trying to display on the console some messages, but I'm getting different results almost every time.It's driving me crazy... This doesn't happen on eclipse though.Here is the code:

```
    package TestngFiles;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Annot {
    @BeforeMethod
    public void userIdGeneratio(){
        System.out.println("User id Generated");
    }
    @Test
    public void aopenningBrowser(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    @Test
    public void flightBooking(){
        System.out.println("Flight Booking");
    }
}
```

And here are some results:

```
User id Generated
User id Generated
Flight Booking

Process finished with exit code 0



User id Generated
test
User id Generated
Flight Booking

Process finished with exit code 0




User id Generated

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: so you started the mentioned test class 3 times and you get the following result? Can you share your testng.xml with us?

Comment: I started the test like 5 times and the first 3 times the result was the same as the first one posted here so I didn't post them. I don't have any testng.xml file. This was just a simple exercise project as I'm currently learning the testNG framework.

Comment: What I see is that in the first output, the beforeMethod ran 2 times and one of your test. Second output: this is the expected output, and the Third Output: only one beforeMethod. Are you sure that you don't have more @Test? Or did you cancelled the runs maybe?

Comment: Yes, the second output is the correct one. I can't post some photos, but yes I'm 100% sure I don't have any more @Test and I didn't cancel any runs. I also have to mention that the test statuses are all passed, I can't see any problems there.Only the console output has problems.

Comment: If you run your test, at the beginning of the console output there will be the path for the xml file. Can you please copy the content of it? I'm really interested that how it looks, because I don't understand why you get the following outputs :)

Comment: I don't have the path for the xml instead I have different paths. I  also have to mention that if I expand the tests in the left side I end up with all the results but missplaced.Sometimes some outputs show up at the wrong methods. http://imageshack.com/a/img537/4651/nS1Jov.png

Comment: Sometimes they show up all outputs as expected for like 200ms and quickly collapse to some wrong result as I showed you above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is know issue with IntelliJ TestNG plugin. IntelliJ itself is a great tool, but this plugin is substandard. It has bugs and it doesn't refer to most recent TestNG xml schema document. It has not been maintained for a good while, I wrote about that:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2014/03/16/intellij-idea-and-outdated-testng-j-plugin/

You should not rely on TestNG console output in IntelliJ, it is in permanent quirks mode. One time output will be here, another it won't. You can't do anything about it. Just live with it.